# Drawerlayout is intercepting all touch events

Tags: android, navigation-drawer, drawerlayout

My drawerLayout is intercepting all touch events. I need help figuring out how to click on elements below it. Here is how my drawerLayout is set up

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/frag_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <RelativeLayout
        .... some code ...

    </RelativeLayout>
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

I then reference this layout in another layout like this

```
    <!-- elements inside of this relative layout 
    are unclickable because the drawer layout below 
    intercepts all clicks. If I place the drawer above 
    this view the drawer is beneath all the elements 
    in the relative layout, however, I am able to do 
    my clicks as expected. What I am doing incorrectly? -->

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <!-- ... some code * the buttons here are what 
        I want to be clickable when drawer is closed. 
        I currently cannot reach them ... -->

    </RelativeLayout>

 <include layout="@layout/drawer" />

</FrameLayout>
```

I have added `android:clickable="false"` and `android:focusable="false"` in the xml on the drawer. Programmatically I logged the clicks, and it is the actual drawer with id "drawer_layout" intercepting all clicks. Making it unclickable does not work, it is still clickable. I also tried setting the visibility to INVISIBLE and GONE and these are not viable solutions either.

How can I make that drawerLayout allow clicks through it to elements beneath it? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured this out. I ended up adding my main layout to the drawer which is the reverse of what I was doing before because before I was adding the drawer to my main layout. So the change I made was

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/frag_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >
        <include layout="@layout/main_layout" />
    </FrameLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        .... some code ...

    </RelativeLayout>
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

If anyone else runs into this problem it is view hierarchy conflict. You cannot have your drawer on top of elements that you want to interact it. If you have buttons or other widgets that you need to interact it you should include it to your drawer layout instead. I hope this helps someone else out there.

Answer (score 1):

By setting clickable and focusable to false, I think you are disabling click to the views in the layout too. Remove these options from the drawer layout.
Try setting android:clickable="true" and android:focusable="true" for the container inside the drawer layout.

Comment: Sorry, good theory but not working still. drawerLayout intercepts all clicks, and if I set focusable and clickable to false on drawerLayout, the Framelayout beneath that will then intercept all clicks. Setting both to false results in the drawer not working properly, e.g. I am unable to slide it out or worse.

Comment: So I am a little confused, which element should receive the clicks ?

Comment: The views beneath the drawer. I "include" the drawer layout on my main layout. The include is at the bottom, which means it is on top of the elements that I want to interact with while the drawer is closed. I have no access to those elements since the drawer layout is on top of it. I want to be able to click through the drawer to the elements beneath it.

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of your activity ? as in why is the drawer intercepting clicks once it's closed?

Comment: It intercepts the clicks because drawer_layout is set to match_parent. It is the top view.

Comment: Thanks anyway for your help

Comment: Any reason your drawer layout is as big as the parent ?